# How to use pagination in BusyBox when ‘more’ is dysfunctional?

Tags: boot, initramfs, busybox

So I’m dropped in Busybox and need to do some work here (no pools, datasets and encrypted root) but `more` isn’t working properly.

I need to go through the config files but I have access to a few degraded commands and fail to set pagination.

I am not very confident with those tools, never been there that long

Thank you

Comment: I haven't booted into BusyBox for a while but I think that `less` is in there.

Comment: No it’s not, don’t know why. And the one there have nearly no options, no ˋhelpˋ  available with them and the list is different than the man doc. 
In ˋgrubˋ I can set it with ˋpager=1ˋ but not here

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 21.04 desktop Hirsute Hippo

Comment: That is strange.  When I type in `busybox less` it shows the version and help for the `less` command in my 21.04 VM I have running.  And as a test if I do `cat /etc/group | busybox more` it also seems to work right.  So as far as I can see both commands of more and less are there.  You might need to reinstall your OS to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. Using BusyBox 1.27.2 on initramfs of Max10 (linux 4.15.0-generic #42-Ubuntu.)
"More" waits for keypress when run from console, but not when using pipes.

Edit: I found I could paginate using sed:

```
cat /init |sed -e"30q"
cat /init |sed -e"60q"
```

And so on...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1180243)

Comment: Well, I think the hint about "sed" helps someone needing to edit config files while being trapped in a busybox without it. What does NOT are those messages saying "now that you are trapped in a dysfunctional login, reinstall". The disfunctional busybox could be inside the boot of a linux installer.